# Why are camps REDUCING production?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

I've built a couple of camps and it adds 1 or 2 gold, but actually removes a production.

Is this a bug? (I'm Maori). What's the thinking here, surely this will encourage many people to just stop building camps?

I can't find mention of this anywhere in Google. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not a bug.

The ability "Mana" provides +1 production to **unimproved** forests and rainforests respectively +2 with the Conservation civic.

Since you are improving the tile by adding a camp, you lose this bonus.

Comment: Ahh, so It only affects Maori, and it probably makes sense for the maori to improve these tiles less I guess. Thanks.

Comment: @niico Absolutely. In your case, you trade gold for production. It basically depends on what you need. Keep in mind though that a builder charge also costs production (how much depends on your build charge amount per builder). So you are trading already invested production, and future production for gold.